# Server disk is full - /dev/mapper/system-lv_dados

Tags: disk-space-utilization, sles

I was trying to replace the MariaDB by MySQL on my server. But it happens it won't let me complete the task due to lack of space.

```
pxl0hosp0048:/ # df -h
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-lv_root          9.8G  9.6G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               7.8G  8.7M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                               7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                           478M  116M  334M  26% /boot
/dev/mapper/system-lv_dados         276G   63M  276G   1% /dados
/dev/mapper/system-lv_var            27G  330M   26G   2% /var
/dev/mapper/system-lv_opt           4.8G   11M  4.6G   1% /opt
/dev/mapper/system-lv_tmp           4.8G   11M  4.6G   1% /tmp
172.16.12.98:/dados/compartilhados  276G   63M  276G   1% /mnt/dados98
```

And also...

```
pxl0hosp0048:/ # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A9FE2C95-8600-4ACB-A15D-82418B3A2216

Device     Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 629143551 629141504  300G Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f3ea7

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  1028095  1026048  501M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1028096 62914559 61886464 29.5G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/system-lv_root: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/system-swap: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/system-lv_opt: 5 GiB, 5368709120 bytes, 10485760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/system-lv_tmp: 5 GiB, 5368709120 bytes, 10485760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/system-lv_var: 27.5 GiB, 29532094464 bytes, 57679872 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/system-lv_dados: 280 GiB, 300647710720 bytes, 587202560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

How can I accomplish to free some space in here? Any help will be welcome...

Comment: fyi there's no supported(or likely to work) in-place upgrade path from mariadb to mysql. Take a mysqldump and then try to import that into MySQL after you've done the update.

Comment: Yes.. But this is not the main concern here, it's about managing the system volumes. As I'm mainly a programmer, I'm not familiar with the "how"s and the risks of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd look at `system` volume group using `vgs`, to see if there is any more space in the `system` volume group. If there is 10-20G add that to the `lv_root` logical volume (`lvextend`) and resize the filesystem (resize2fs if ext[34]), as 10G is a bit small for a rootfs, even with other volumes mounted.

If there is no space in `vgs`, umount and resize down another filesystem, and then the volume underneath. And then allocate that to `lv_root`.

Third and least prefered option, remove packages or generally try to find uneeded programs/files on the rootfs.

Comment: main thing to make sure of is the the filesystem is a smaller size than the LV on which it is mounted.

Comment: As a dummy, I needed more details to solve. However, you guided me to find the solution and with the help of the following post, I got to complete the task.

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/